# As a domain/enterprise admin, how can I change permissions on another user's Outlook calendar?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

When I try to go to the properties of another user's calendar it says that I do not have the proper permissions. I'm trying to configure permissions for a remote user's calendar so that their manager can view it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the powershell script Add-MailboxFolderPermissions e.g.

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission "DOMAIN\USERX:\Calendar" -User "DOMAIN\MANAGER" -AccessRights Reviewer
```

From the help contents, The AccessRights parameter specifies the rights needed to perform the operation. Valid values include:

- FullAccess
- SendAs
- ExternalAccount
- DeleteItem
- ReadPermission
- ChangePermission
- ChangeOwner

Comment: What would I set if I just want to give another user Reviewer permissions so they can see the full details of the calendar?

Comment: just use the script as above as it already has "Reviewer" as the access right

Comment: Sorry, should have taken a closer look at the script first, sorry man.